# how do i "View in browser" a mvc 2 app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

This is probably a pretty simple question, but I don't see how to view in browser like I would for a traditional asp.net application.

Comment: I don't know if it makes sense... you mean from a controller action? a route? mmhh...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio, Ctrl + F5 to run without debugging and Cassini will take care of the rest (or do you mean from inside visual studio like you can with webforms)?

Comment: This works for me. If you want to change the default address to open, then you can do so via the Project -> 'Project Name' Properties and see the Web tab.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it seems that [Microsoft has acknowledged this as a bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/340277/asp-net-mvc-view-in-browser).

There are a couple workarounds you can try -- though none of them are exactly what you are looking for. None of them let you start your web page from any arbitrary page simply by right-clicking.

One inexact workaround that is good enough for me is:
If you open up your project properties and go to the Web tab you will see the "Start Action" setting. Change this to "Don't open a page. Wait for a request..."

Now when you start debugging, nothing will happen! (oh no, it's worse!)

Now you can right-click on the Cassini system-tray icon and choose to open the browser from there. You only have to do this on your first session of the day. Once you do this, you can navigate to where you want in your site, and keep that browser window open all day. Letting you start and stop debugging from that point whenever you want.

Again, it isn't exactly the same, but it isn't terrible either.

Answer (score -2):

Just run the Visual Studio Project and it should open the application's **Index view of home controller** by default!

If you are talking about IIS file viewing, in IIS go to your application -> switch to content view -> go to default.aspx -> right click -> choose browse

Comment: There is no default.aspx file in MVC.

Comment: @Junto: There is, atleast till ASP.NET MVC 2.0, I am not sure if that's changed after that.